# Concatenate 0's bits of custom length with a uint8_t array

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation, uint8array

I try to concatenate some bits with the array of type uint8_t in c,as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <Input _message>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
     uint8_t L_length_of_message =strlen(argv[1]);
     num_0's_in_bits_addedd=13; // try to || 13 bit with array
     uint8_t msg[L_length_of_message]; 
//assume this msg is already converted in hex format
```

Now i,e msg=0xabcf123;
and i want concatenate 13(bits) with msg i,e;

```
  msg=0xabcf123;
  msg_in_bits=1010101111001111000100100011
  zeors_added_in_bits=0000000000000;
  new_msg_in_bits=10101011110011110001001000110000000000000;
  new_msg=0x1579e246000
```

The major problem is the message is stored into a char array, so shift operation for multiple bits is not working. suggest some solution for the problem??

Comment: Do you want the result as unsigned integer, as hex string or as array of bits? It's not clear from your pseudocode.

Comment: @user202729 VLA have been C standard for 20 years...

Comment: i want array of bits as out put.